# PHP insert combination to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am fresh learner.

I found a difficulty for "Insert combination data made PHP to MySQL"

Example: for  1,2,3,4, combination is:

```
123
124
134
234
```

I want to insert that into a MySQL database.

Result:

```
123
124
134
234
234 <= duplicate
```

I couldn't locate where is the problem is. Thank you so much. :-)

```
$lista = array($a,$b,$c,$d);
$b=1;

for ($i=0; $i<=3; $i++) {
  for ($j=$b; $j<=4;$j++) {
    for ($k=$j+1; $j<count($lista); $j++) {

       printf($lista[$i].','.$lista[$j].'<br>');

       $sql="INSERT INTO table10(id)
            VALUES($lista[$i]$lista[$j])";
        mysql_query( $sql, $con );

        }           
    }
    $b++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create array to avoid duplicate data

```
$dupList=array();
//declare this array before loop

//Hold  $lista[$i] and $lista[$j] jointly in a variable
$newVal=$lista[$i].$lista[$j];
if (!in_array($newVal, $dupList)) {

      $sql="INSERT INTO table10(id) VALUES ($newVal)";
      mysql_query( $sql, $con );
      array_push($dupList,$newVal);
}
```

Comment: My array logic isn't very good, after I added this to my code. It appear an error. "syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE< start from IF..... Is it something wrong to me? The code I added as another, please comment. Thank you so much

Comment: Hi, I upadted the codes, it seems work, but the record is still duplicated. I felt a sense of shame, is it something wrong on me. I took almost 2 hrs try to fix it. It doesn't work. Can I send my control panel to let u check. T^T.

Comment: what in `$lista = array($a,$b,$c,$d);` $a,$b,$c and $d ?

Comment: $a=$_POST[no1];
$b=$_POST[no2];
$c=$_POST[no3];
$d=$_POST[no4];  All are number inputted by user what number they want from a simple form website.

Answer (score 1):

My array logic isn't very good, after I added this to my code. It appear an error.

> syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE<
>   start from IF.....
>   Is it something wrong to me? The code I added as below.

```
$lista = array($a,$b,$c,$d);
$dupList=array();
//declare this array before loop
$b=1;


for ($i=0; $i<=3; $i++) {
    for ($j=$b; $j<=4;$j++) {
        for ($k=$j+1; $j<count($lista); $j++) {
            if (!in_array($lista[$i]$lista[$j], $dupList)) {
                $sql="INSERT INTO table10(id) VALUES ($lista[$i]$lista[$j])";
                mysql_query( $sql, $con );
                array_push($dupList,$lista[$i]$lista[$j]);
                }
            }
        }
    $b++;
}
```